# Optional '/' in AWS Elastic Loadbalancer Listener Rule

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm trying to add a path-based listener rule to my [Loadbalancer Listener Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule-conditions.html). The regex would come to `\/?[A-Za-z]*\/foo\/[A-Za-z]*`.

Some match examples:

1. `/context/foo/bar`
2. `/foo/bar`

So I've looked into parsing this regex into a [RuleCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_RuleCondition.html). So far I've come up with `/*/foo/*`. This would match `1` but not `2`. `/foo/*` would match `2` but not `1` on the other hand. So using 2 separate rules is definitely a possible solution for my use case.

However, ideally I'd like to solve this with just 1 rule. Is there any way that would be possible, something I might have possibly overlooked?

I've tried `/?*/foo/*` but the `?` is not used as an optional quantifier apparantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/*foo/*` is somewhat imprecise but it does match both patterns

`*/foo/*` is a little better, maybe, if the service will accept it, but still somewhat imprecise.

These are the closest you can get.  Both could be problematic since `*` will match any 0 or more characters, including `/`, so `/buzz/fizz/foo/bar` would also match.

The first (not best) match is used, so as long as you capture any conflicting paths earlier in the list, either of these might work.

The `?` is a wildcard for matching exactly one character.